# Jquery $("img").click(function() selector not working

Tags: jquery, html, selector

For some reason when I click on an image with this JQuery code the alert screen doesn't show up.

HTML:

```
<div id="example1">
 <div>
  <div>
   <div class="user">
    <img class="Image" src="images/image.jpg">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("img").click(function(){
  alert("it works!");
 });
});
```

I cant figure out why this isn't working I included the jquery library and the `<script>` tag is under the div

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/446/

Comment: has you included the jquery library before this javascript code?

Comment: check your console for errors

Comment: I know i just cant get it working on my .html page in xampp it just doesnt respont to the click

Comment: working fine. i am almost sure, you imported jquery wrong.

Comment: have you disabled popups or suppressed alerts?

Comment: click ``f12`` and see what console says.

Comment: yes i included jquery in the <head> im getting one console error:

Comment: error: 'Attr.nodeValue' is deprecated. Please use 'value' instead.

Comment: <head> <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> </head> should work right?

Comment: @StefandeRaadt yes think link should work.

Comment: then it isnt the jquery link i enabled popups it works when i add the selector body instead of img so thats not the problem

Comment: Is there another event happening first that is then canceling propogation?

Comment: it just cant reach the img for some reason i cant figure out why

Comment: @StefandeRaadt you must have a "bad" html so that your ``img`` cannot be reached. check for html bugs

Comment: The code you've supplied works; so: what othe JavaScript/jQuery have you got on the page that may be interfering?

Comment: im getting this error is this maybe the problem?: 'Attr.nodeValue' is deprecated. Please use 'value' instead.

Comment: Im using a jquery plugin to get the html image from twitter from people who used #Image maybe this plugin stops it from working?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

the img isn't in the DOM when your event handler is registered. you can use `$('body').on('click','img',function(){alert('it works');})`

Comment: Or: ```$('img').bind('click', function(){...});```

Comment: Well, only "$('body').on('click','img',function(){alert('it works');})" works, but not $('img').bind('click', function(){...});  I wonder why.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than run your code in document.ready(), you should use window.load() function instead.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("img").click(function(){
        alert("it works!");
     });
});
```

- document.ready() is a jQuery event, it runs when the DOM is ready, e.g.
  all elements are there to be found/used, but not necessarily all
  content.
- window.load() fires later (or at the same time in the
  worst/failing cases) when images and such are loaded, so if you're
  using image dimensions for example, you often want to use this
  instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Image").click(function(){
    alert("it works!");
   });
  });
```

**IF you want your code to work with out change just put .Image not img the class name not attribue name**

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works with images coming from an ajax request too.

```
$(document).on('click','img',function(){
alert("Click event works!");
});
```